# Custom function to allow only expected data in submissions

Tags: php, forms, function, loops, post

I have a function that allows only expected data from form submissions. I was using it before and it was working fine but now when I try to use it. it throws an error: `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` I've tried using `is_array()` function but that didn't fix the error. any idea why this happening.

**Function**

```
  function allowed_post_params($allowed_params=[]) {
    $allowed_array = [];
    foreach ($allowed_params as $param) {
        if (isset($_POST[$param])) {
            $allowed_array[$param] = $_POST[$param];
        } else {
            $allowed_array[$param] = NULL;
        }
    }
    return $allowed_array;
  }
```

**Use in Processing**

```
if (is_post_request()) {

  $post_params = allowed_post_params('email', 'username', 'password', 'country');
  $email = $post_params['email']  ?? '';
  $username = $post_params['username'] ?? '';
  $password = $post_params['password'] ?? '';
  $country = $post_params['country'] ?? '';

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are supplying 4 `string` arguments to the function.

```
$post_params = allowed_post_params('email', 'username', 'password', 'country');
```

It should be a single `array`:

```
$post_params = allowed_post_params(['email', 'username', 'password', 'country']);
```

Comment: Yep, now I noticed. I don't know how I missed that. thank you.